How to formulate SSH Script for TPLink Router
I've been able to SSH into my TPLink Router (ER605) and create a VLAN successfully.

But when I try to send the same commands through a script, it doesn't work. So far, I've tried netmiko/paramiko (python), bat files, and ps1 files.
Here's the contents of the commands.txt file:
enable
configure
vlan 11
name created_using_automated_SSH
exit
exit

And here is the script:
# Variables
$router_ip = "192.168.0.1"
$username = "admin"
$password = "password_goes_here"
$plink_path = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"  # Adjust this path as needed

# Read commands from the file
$commands = Get-Content -Path "commands.txt" -Raw

# Construct the plink command
$plink_command = "&'$plink_path' -ssh $username@$router_ip -pw $password -batch -m commands.txt"

# Execute the plink command and capture output and error
Write-Output "Executing plink command..."
$output = Invoke-Expression $plink_command 2>&1 | Out-String

# Display the output
Write-Output "Output:"
Write-Output $output

# Check if the VLAN creation was successful
if ($output -like "*VLAN creation and configuration completed*") {
    Write-Output "VLAN created successfully"
} else {
    Write-Output "VLAN creation failed. Please check the router configuration."
}

The script is able to authenticate and log into the router, but unable to execute any commands, which otherwise work when done manually over PuTTy.
It prints:
Executing plink command...
Output:
Match mac success
continue IP type
Match mac success
continue IP type
Match mac success

VLAN creation failed. Please check the router configuration.

Any help on how to go about it, would be really appreciated!
Many thanks!
